# No pressure in irrigation system

Tags: irrigation, sprinkler-system

Last summer the sprinklers worked fine but when trying to replace them with drip we found the water no longer flowed. I opened the pressure regulator to inspect if it was blocked but it seemed fine. I can hear the gurgling of water when I turn on the system either with the actuator or manually. But water just barely flows out and only at the first sprinkler outlet. There may be some dirt or stones in the pipes. Is there any way to clear out the pipes without water pressure? Or how can I troubleshoot the lack of pressure?

Comment: did your pipes freeze?

Comment: No, it's quite warm.

Comment: did something get blown loose, or cut then?

Comment: No. We capped most of the sprinklers while working on the yard in preparation for installing drip conversion kits. Now the water just barely comes out at the first uncapped outlet.

Comment: it sounds more like a diy problem, you should post it on https://diy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you irrigate from a reservoir, or do you connect your system to the municipal water supply? The former may yield low pressure, and the water may carry particles which may clog your drip outlet

Comment: @ChristmasSnow it's a municipal water supply.

Comment: I can advise you to pull-out one dripper at-a-time while the tap is on. See if water rushes-out when you do it. There is a chance (I raise it as a possibility) that you have let-in some soil or other dirt and clogged the system somewhere along the way.